# Convert unicode to HTML entities function

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8, html-entities, html-encode

I have the following function that converts unicode to HTML entities, but if I run the function again over the result it will not leave the HTML entities in tact.  How can I get the function to leave already converted HTML entities alone?

```
sub convert_unicode {
    use HTML::Entities;
    use Encode;
    my $str = shift;
    Encode::_utf8_off($str);
    return encode_entities(decode('utf8',$str));
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for `encode_entities(encode_entities("&foo"))` to return `&amp;foo` rather than `&amp;amp;foo`? If so, that's not a good way to handle encoding. Encode *once*.

Comment: @Schwern I may run the my entire function more than once over strings and I want it to leave existing HTML entities alone.

Comment: There's no reason to place (non-pragma) `use` statements in subs.

Comment: NEVER EVER USE `_utf8_off`. Maybe you meant to use `Encode::encode_utf8`?

Comment: @ikegami `_utf8_off` is the only way to handle certain situations.  I don't remember exactly what it does but I had to put it in.

Comment: @ikegami I don't see what the problem is in using `use` in a sub.

Comment: @CJ7, Why would you want to? The effects of the `use` aren't limited to the sub. So 1) it hides the `use` statements for no reason, and 2) it's misleading, since it implies a scoping that doens't exist.

Comment: @CJ7, Use `encode`, `decode`, `downgrade` or `upgrade`, but NEVER `_utf8_on` and `_utf8_off`

Comment: @ikegami Ok, seems like `utf8::downgrade` would achieve the same thing.  Is there any reason to use that instead of `_utf8_off`?

Comment: @ikegami Using `use` inside a sub is just easier and makes more sense because you know what modules the sub is relying on.

Comment: @CJ7, No, `Encode::_utf8_off($str)` is very very different than `utf8::downgrade($str)`. `Encode::_utf8_off($str)` is equivalent to `utf8::encode($str) if _is_utf8($str);` (One shouldn't use `_is_utf8`, which is why you shouldn't use `_utf8_off`.)

Comment: You've got very badly organized code if you need to know what module a *sub* relies on.

Comment: @ikegami `utf8::downgrade` "can be used to make sure that the UTF-8 flag is off" (from the docs)

Comment: Yes, which is very very different than what `Encode::_utf8_off($str);` does. For example: `perl -MEncode -E'my $s = Encode::decode_utf8("\xC3\xA9");  utf8::downgrade( my $s1 = $s ); Encode::_utf8_off( my $s2 = $s ); say sprintf "%vX", $_ for $s, $s1, $s2'`

Comment: @ikegami `_utf8_off` "turns the STRING's internal UTF8 flag off" (from the docs)

Comment: `_utf8_off` changes the flag that indicates how the string is stored, period. Changing that flag that indicates how the string is stored without changing how it's stored effectively changes the string (and can result in a corrupted scalar). ///  `utf8::dowgrade` changes how the string is stored. It doesn't change the string.

Comment: @ikegami Ok, are you suggesting use of `utf8::downgrade` instead of `_utf8_off`?

Comment: I don't know why you're using `_utf8_off`. Depending on the input, it either does the same thing as `utf8::encode` or does nothing at all. That's why I suggested you might want to use `utf8::encode`.

Comment: I found that it prevents errors in the next line of my code above.

Comment: Trying to decode something that's not encoded would definitely result in errors. Of course, you could get rid of both the encode and the decode...

Comment: I'm coming at it from a practical perspective, simply wanting a general function to convert potential unicode characters to entities. I run it over all strings as part of a larger process because the final target is HTML. I found without the `_utf8_off` line there are sometimes errors in the next line.

Comment: Re "*Using use inside a sub is just easier and makes more sense because you know what modules the sub is relying on.*", A far better solution for this is to explicitly list the functions you import. e.g. `use HTML::Entities qw( encode_entities ); use Encode qw( decode );`

Comment: 1) I never suggested that you remove `_utf8_off`. I just said it needs to be replaced. 2) You may be using is to attempt to fix another bug (but introduce another bug in the process)

Comment: @ikegami Yes but that is right at the top of my module which contains a lot of functions.  You would have to scroll all the way up to see the imports.

Comment: @CJ7, Well, right now, you need to load the pod pages of those modules, so that's much further away!

Comment: @ikegami I don't think there is any bug. The input is strings that may have unicode.  The final target is HTML so any unicode must be converted to entities.

Comment: Re "*I don't think there is any bug.*", You're using `_utf8_off`, so you have at least one since your code suffers from The Unicode Bug. NEVER USE `_utf8_off`

Comment: @ikegami I'm not interested in a mantra. The problem is quite simple. Convert any unicode in strings to entities. There are sometimes errors in the final line.  The preceding line removes those errors.

Comment: Demonstration of the bug: `use Test::More tests => 2;

use charnames qw( :full );

sub convert_unicode {
    use HTML::Entities;
    use Encode;
    my $str = shift;
    Encode::_utf8_off($str);
    return encode_entities(decode('utf8',$str));
}

my $s = "\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE}";
utf8::downgrade( my $d = $s );
utf8::upgrade( my $u = $s );

ok($d eq $u);
ok(convert_unicode($d) eq convert_unicode($u));
`

Comment: It removes some errors and adds others. Your `convert_unicode` sometimes converts `é` to `&#xFFFD;` and sometimes converts it to `&eacute;`.

Comment: @ikegami Can you explain that?  I don't understand how it could be different sometimes.

Comment: It's because you use `_utf8_off`. Sometimes it does nothing; sometimes it encodes using UTF-8, and the decision is based on how the string is stored (an internal detail). This is called "The Unicode Bug".

Comment: Would the problem be avoided if I used `utf8::downgrade`?

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking for is to be able to safely double character encode. Some encodings allow this. HTML character encoding does not because it uses certain characters like `&` to do the encoding and it cannot tell the difference between a special character being used for encoding and one that needs to be encoded.

For example...

```
use HTML::Entities;
use v5.10;
say encode_entities("&foo");
```

That produces `&amp;foo`. If we encode it again it produces `&amp;amp;foo` because `&` is a special character which it faithfully encodes. ***It does not know that `&amp;` is an already encoded `&`*** so it treats it as a literal `&amp;` and encodes it.

You *could* write your own custom HTML encoding function that assumes `&xxx;` (and its variants) are already encoded, but that's just a guess. You can't actually tell a literal `&foo;` and an encoded `&foo;` apart. It will break with, for example, old school Perl code like `&function;`. Maybe you can be *super clever* and use an array of objects to indicate which parts are encoded and have the whole thing overload stringification so it looks like a string, and so long as everything carefully preserves that object that looks like a string it'll work...

And now we're into the [lava flow anti-pattern](http://antipatterns.com/lavaflow.htm) where rather than fixing bad design, more complex and bad design is layered on top of it. Trying to "fix" that will just create more problems. The real problem lies deeper.

---

The real problem is that you're encoding multiple times. This probably means you've wielded your formatting and your functionality together. For example...

```
sub get_user_name {
    my $uid = shift;

    my $name = ...do a bunch of work to get the user name...

    return encode_entities($name);
}
```

By HTML encoding the data, a function like this makes assumptions about how the data is going to be used. It limits its use to just HTML. If all your functions do this, you have a double encoding problem.

Then maybe you have something like this:

```
sub do_something {
    my $uid = shift;

    # $name is already HTML encoded.
    my $name = get_user_name($uid);

    my $stuff = ...something incorporating $name...

    # Whoops, the user name is double encoded.
    return encode_entities($stuff);
}
```

The answer is to leave the HTML formatting and encoding until the last minute. Ideally don't do it at all, just work with data and let an HTML template system take care of it. [Template Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Template-Toolkit/lib/Template/Manual/Intro.pod), for example.

This also provides a clean separation between the formatting and the code, so now non-programmers can work on the formatting using a documented template system.